# Use multiple multipages HTML files with Phonegap and jQuery Mobile doesn't work on iOS

Tags: html, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, hyperlink

I am trying to figure out how to use multiple HTML files with multiple jQuery Mobile pages inside an iOS app built with Phonegap.

The first file "home.html" loads properly and can link to different pages within this file using:

```
<a href="#contact" data-transition="slide">About</a>
```

And the contact page div in the same file:

```
<div data-role="page" id="contact" class="page">
```

This works fine on iOS and loading an HTML file works as well:

```
<a href="feesAndCharges.html">Fees and charges</a>
```

The problem is, once I reach this second HTML file, links to pages inside this file don't work on the iOS simulator but work fine on the desktop web browser.

Comment: Have you read this page: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html

Comment: I think I've read this already, but I must have skipped the part about the absolute urls.
I changed the link :
`<a href="feesAndCharges.html">Fees and charges</a>`

to :

`<a href="file://localhost/Users/blablabla/feesAndCharges.html">Fees and charges</a>`

and now it works fine on the iOS simulator! Thanks!